# Of what is "ffdshow" an abbreviation?

Tags: ffdshow

I've searched this site as well as a few other sites as well to get the abbreviation of ffdshow to find no answer at all. It may look kind of pedantic and strange, but I would like to know it. So, Is there anyone who can answer me what ffdshow stands for?

Comment: there's no full form bro

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `ffdshow` was created in 2002 as Windows DirectShow port/host of `libavcodec`, and `libavcodec` itself is a multipurpose codec library maintained by the FFmpeg Project since 2000, so the name "ffdshow" was likely the name was chosen as a reference to the FFmpeg Project.

ffdshow basically allows `libavcodec` to be used by DirectShow-based applications on Windows, so any DirectShow program (Windows Media Player, Windows Media Center, Winamp, Musicmatch, Media Player Classic - and the media-players built-in to other software like KaZaA and Internet Explorer 6's Media sidebar) can play file formats supported by `libavcodec`.

The FFmpeg project itself is named after the ["Fast-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_forward)" transport control in AV:

http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2006-February/010315.html

> [Fabrice Bellard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabrice_Bellard)
>
> Sat Feb 18 19:38:28 CET 2006
>
> Just for the record, the original meaning of "FF" in FFmpeg is "Fast 
>   Forward"...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fabric Bellard. It's Fast Forward Direct Show. Thank you again.